# Равномерное распределение чисел

Tags: php, нейронные-сети

Для нейронной сети нужно привести значения к шкале от 0 до 1

```
$arr = [-7, 1, 99, -7.3, -6]; //в реальном десятки тысяч элементов
```

Нужно по нему построить кривую, примерно такую:
[image: кривая]
   
и по значению найти точку на шкале. В нашем случае для -4 должно быть 0.6

Comment: И? У вас вопрос с нормализацией?

Comment: Да, хотел по такой формуле(y = (ymax-ymin) * (x-xmin) / (xmax-xmin) + ymin), но неравномерное распределение получается.

Comment: А зачем в y-координату подмешивать x? Я бы увеличил все значения на число dy, чтобы минимальное из чисел набора стало нулем, потом разделил бы все на максимальное получившееся...

Comment: Такой подход конечно красивее при диапазоне от 0 до 1, но по сути то же самое вид с боку https://ideone.com/fO3Jez

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = [-7, 1, 99, -7.3, -6];

//Находим максимальное и минимальное значения в массиве
$min = min($arr);
$max = max($arr);

//Создаем новый массив, где максимальное значение будет соответствовать единице, 
//а минимальное нулю
$new_arr = array_map(function($y){
    $y = ($y - $min)/($max - $min);
}, $arr);
```

приблизительный ход дальнейшего решения:

1. ищем среднее значение величины (это будет пик нашего графика):
   `$average = array_sum($new_arr)/count($new_arr);`
2. составляем таблицу вероятностей той или иной величины, в зависимости от отклонения от среднего с придуманным шагом и сохраняем в массив:
3. Делаем обратное преобразование к нашим изначальным данным.
4. Строим график.

Comment: То же само что и здесь(https://ideone.com/fO3Jez) , только раздуто. Не равномерно распределение от 0 до 1.

Comment: Я не понимаю, что имеется в виду под словом "равномерное"? Нужно отсортировать массив так, что получился график равномерного распределения величины? Тогда это чисто математическая задача и решается математическими методами. php тут ни при чем.